# Recurrent and transient states

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, transition-matrix

[image]

I know which are the recurrent states {2,4,5} and It's clear to see it drawing a diagram but how can I prove that {2,4,5} are the recurrent states?

In a formal way?

Also the transient states are {0,1,3} but I saw it intuitively, how can I prove it formally?

Comment: In terms of first return probabilities, a state j is recurrent if $\sum_{n=1}^{n}f_{jj}^{(n)}=1$, and transient if $\sum_{n=1}^{n}f_{jj}^{(n)}<1$.

Comment: I think you mean $ \infty$ instead of n. Don't you? @L.V.Rao

Comment: yes.  a typo. sorry about that.

Comment: In terms of first return probabilities, a state j is recurrent if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_{jj}^{(n)}=1$, and transient if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_{jj}^{(n)}<1.$

Comment: So now I have to prove this $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_{22}^{(n)}=1$ ?

Comment: How do I prove the above equation? @L.V.Rao

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use First Entrance Theorem, which states that for any states $i$ and $j$ and integer $n\geq 1$,
\begin{equation*}
p_{ij}^{(n)}=\sum_{m=1}^{n}f_{ij}^{(m)}p_{jj}^{(n-m)}
\end{equation*}
where the zero-transition probabilities are defined by
\begin{equation*}
p_{ij}^{(0)}=\begin{cases}
1,& \text{ if } i=j\\
0,& \text{ if } i\neq j\\
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
If state space is moderately large, then the following recursive formula will be useful:
\begin{equation*}
F^{(n+1)}=P\left( F^{(n)}-F_{d}^{(n)}\right)
\end{equation*}
where $P$ is the transition probability matrix of a Markov chain, $F^{(n)}=\left(f_{ij}^{(n)}\right)$ and  $F_{d}^{(n)}$ denotes a diagonal matrix containing the diagonal elements of $F^{(d)}$.

Comment: seems difficult :(

Comment: Shall I update one of your earlier posts?

Comment: Have look at the updated for one of your earlier questions - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2268165/determining-the-first-return-distribution-of-mc/2268240#2268240              Is it useful, now? Look at the diagonal elements.

Comment: Thanks my friend. Thanks for trying to help me.

Comment: Thanks. I thank  MSE for giving me this opportunity.

Comment: oh yeah you're right thanks god MSE exist